# how to calculate top X% of viewers watches 50% of all views

Tags: sql, hive

first time here so if i did something wrong, please let me know and i'll change it. i am trying to answer the business question (hypothetically): what % of video views do the top youtube viewers make up? i.e. the top 50% of all video views come from the top 5% of youtube watchers.

i have a table A such as:

```
watcher id | video id | number of watches| date 
123        | abc      | 2                | 11/16/2021
```

sample data using just one video and one day worth of data:

```
123 | same video | 5 | same date
456 | same video | 1 | same date 
789 | same video | 1 | same date
```

in this case, my expected result is: 1/3(33%) of the watchers watched 5/7 (71%) of this video on this date.

one way i could think of doing something like this is the following:

```
select watcher id 
, sum(number of watches) as nw 
from table A 
where date between x and y 
group by watcher id 
) 

, top as (
select sum(number of watches) as nw_top 
, count(distinct watcher id) as num_in_top 
from relationship 
where nw>30
) 

select count(distinct watcher id) as total_watchers
, sum(nw) as nw 
from relationship 
union all 
select num_in_top
, nw_top 
from top
```

using that i can calculate the top X% of video views that are watched by the top % of watchers.
anything wrong with the logic there?

Comment: What business question are you trying to answer?  state it in plain English.  I'm struggling with your question because 30% of what people?   or are you saying between dates x,y what is the most watched video and how many people in that date range watched it from the total?

Comment: its seems like you may wnat to use analytic/window functions such as `sum(numberofWatches) over (partition by video)` to get total watches of a video to get a denominator for your % calculations...  but the question is just too vague to understand.  Use more example data and expected results even if it's a small subset

Comment: @xQbert thanks, i edited the question a bit. also will post here. 
(hypothetically): what % of video views do the top youtube viewers make up? i.e. the top 50% of all video views come from the top 5% of youtube watchers.

Comment: What are your tries?

Comment: @LeandroBardelli thanks for the comment. i added in my attempt in the original post